# переменная вместо индекса значения в списке

Tags: python

Делаю запрос

```
resultfromsteam = requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeOffers/v1/?key=' + api + '&get_sent_offers=1&active_only=1').json()
```

Получаю список,в котором затем указываю индекс элемента.
Еще есть цикл for,в котором я узнаю,сколько мне надо сделать индексов.

```
d = len(resultfromsteam['response']['trade_offers_sent'])
print(d)
for i in range(d + 1):
```

далее,хочу поочередно ставить i.

```
tradestate = resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent'][]['trade_offer_state']
```

как это можно сделать?

Comment: `resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent'][i]['trade_offer_state']`?

Comment: Что сделать? Куда ставить? Что мешает поставить?

Comment: @nomnoms12 неа(

Comment: i поставить вместо индекса,пишет,что неверный индекс

Comment: @artemso72 Что неа?) Измените цикл на `for i in range(d):` и должно работать. У Вас выход за пределы (`index out of range`). Нумерация с 0 начинается.

Comment: @nomnoms12 спасибо,работает.Забыл что с 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Измените `range(d + 1)` на `range(d)`, а затем просто подставьте `i`.

Диапазон, генерируемый функцией `range` в Вашем случае выглядит так: `[0, d)`.
То есть, нумерация начинается с `0`, а правая граница не включается.

Нумерация списков начинается тоже с `0`.
Если длина списка равна `d`, то индекс последнего элемента списка равен `d - 1`.

Поэтому в Вашем коде и возникает ошибка, Вы выходите за границы списка, пытаясь получить элемент с индексом `d`.

***Код:***

```py
...
d = len(resultfromsteam['response']['trade_offers_sent'])

for i in range(d):
    tradestate = resultfromsteam["response"]['trade_offers_sent'][i]['trade_offer_state']
```